# 503 Service Unavailable when Load Balancer is active

Tags: load-balancing

We have two cloud servers from Hetzner. The web server is Nginx. Both servers are identical (hardware, software and our web application).

LetsEncrypt certificate is installed on both servers. Nginx is configured to redirect `http` to `https`.

The DNS server is Cloudflare. We switch the IP address of our domain's A record manually from Server A to Server B or vice versa.

Now we have created a Load Balancer in Hetzer with our two servers and one service: `https 443 -> 443`.

As soon as we change the IP address of the A record of our domain to the IP address of LB, we receive `503 service unavailable`.

Please assist.

Comment: Read log files on your webs server and your load balancer.

Comment: If you're using Hetzner's managed load-balancer, there should be somewhere in their web interface some way to get logs and/or status of backend connections (to server A and B).
ALso, usually the load-balancer make the SSL termination, thus you may need to configurer let'sencrypt certificate there. https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/configure-lb-cert-with-external-domain

Comment: @Saïmonn Thanks. Apparently there's no log, and the certificate is already configured. I think we should not have the SSL certificates installed on the server and we should let LB to handle that otherwise I don't understand why LB needs the CA and KEY of my certificate.

Comment: @OmidShojaee in that case, your load-balancer should be configured to use serverA and serverB as http backend on port 80, not 443.

Comment: @Saïmonn So LB for http 80 -> 80 and Nginx handles 80 -> 443 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a load-balancer for SSL termination, your nginx should not listen on tcp port 443 nor have a certificate.
nginx should only listen on port 80, and the load-balancer shoud:

- have a certificate ([hetzner LB can apparently manage LetEncrypt certificates](https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/load-balancers/faq/#how-can-i-manage-my-certificates))
- listen on port 443 (source), and redirect to nginx port 80 (destination), with SSL proxy in between.

To manage the http to https redirection, if the load-balancers are able to do it, that's the best option. If not, then on nginx side you will have to detect if the client connects with https or http (sometimes the load-balancer can set a header with this information), and redirect if it's cleartext http.

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of answer I was looking for.